# csrf token for ajax serialize data in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am putting csrf token for my all ajax call but I'm getting error 500 where I am passing serialize data and JSON data in my ajax call.
I included in my view page but it's not working and throwing an error.

```
$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
            if(validateCode()){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'verifyCode', // form action url
                    type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post       
                    data: $('#frm').serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                    result = JSON.parse(result);
                    if(result.st == 1){
                        window.location.href="backupCode";
                    }
                    else{
                            $('#validCodeFormat').html("<span style='color:red'>Invalid authentication code.</span>");
                    } 
                    },
                    error: function(e) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });  

var json='json={"age":"'+age+'","age1":"'+age1+'","afterTaxincome":"'+aftertaxincome+'","afterTaxincome2":"'+aftertaxincome2+'","annualSave":"'+annualSave+'","annualSave2":"'+annualSave2+'","liqInvest":"'+liqInvest+'","liqInvest2":"'+liqInvest2+'","nonliqassets":"'+nonliqassets+'","nonliqassets2":"'+nonliqassets2+'","totalLia":"'+totalLia+'","totalLia2":"'+totalLia2+'","savingsChange":"'+savingsChange+'","savingsChange2":"'+savingsChange2+'","preference":"'+preference+'","market":"'+market+'","mail":"'+mail+'","investorTypePage":"'+investortype+'"}';
                //alert(json);
            $.ajax({url: "questions/sendQuestions",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: json,
                    success: function(result){


                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, errMsg) {
                        alert("error while fetching data from server.\nPlease try again.");
                    }
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `$.ajaxSetup()` before your AJAX calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrf_token = {TOKEN};

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have needed this before when using [Flask CSRF Protection](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html#javascript-requests).